# Wrong type argument: keymapp, emacs-lisp-mode-map

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have the following lines in my init.el:

```
(dolist (map '(emacs-lisp-mode-map
           lisp-interaction-mode-map))
  (define-key map (kbd "C-c C-e") 'eval-and-replace))
```

When I eval it, I get an error:

```
Wrong type argument: keymapp, emacs-lisp-mode-map
```

But if I check with:

```
(keymapp emacs-lisp-mode-map)
```

the result is:

```
t
```

I have no idea what's wrong with that
I have also tried another version of mapcar:

```
(mapcar '(lambda (map)
       (define-key map (kbd "C-c C-e") 'eval-and-replace))
    '(emacs-lisp-mode-map
      lisp-interaction-mode-map))
```

but the result is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`define-key` expects an actual keymap as its first argument. You are passing it a **symbol** (variable) whose **value is a keymap**.  You need to use this:

```
(dolist (map  (list emacs-lisp-mode-map lisp-interaction-mode-map))...)
```

`list` is a normal function, so it evaluates its arguments.  In this case, that gives you a list of two keymaps, not two keymap variables (symbols).  In the code you used, `quote` just returns the list `(emacs-lisp-mode-map lisp-interaction-mode-map)`.

You tested `(keymapp emacs-lisp-mode-map)`. But if you had tested `(keymapp 'emacs-lisp-mode-map)` then the result would have been `nil`: a symbol is not a keymap.